# How to change the color of Image text with Image map in html5

Tags: jquery, html, imagemap

hi i have an image on which in particular portion if i roll over my mouse then the text that is in the image, its color should get changed on hover. I have applied the code through which i am able to use image map and if i roll over my mouse in that area it shows the blue patch. But that is not working smoothly. Please help me out that how can i change the text color in image. As well as is that a correct way that I am using. Thanks in advance.

The code that I am using is:
HTML:

```
<map id="map1" name="whatever" style="display:none">
        <area id="1" href="#" shape="rect" coords="10,10,200,150" style="border: black 1px solid"/>
    </map>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="rect" style=" position:absolute; background-color:#039; display:none" ></div>
        <img id="tnt"  src="images/image1.png" usemap="#whatever" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var abc = $('#map1');
        var x, y, id_ = "", arr, k = "";
        var ttt = $('#rect').position();
        var tre = $('#tnt').position();
        abc.hover(function (e) {
            id_ = '#' + e.target.id;
            arr = ($(id_).attr('coords')).split(',');
            //alert("hello")
            arr[0] = arr[0] * 1;
            arr[1] = arr[1] * 1;
            $('#rect').css('left', tre.left + arr[0]);
            $('#rect').css('top', tre.top + arr[1]);
            $('#rect').css('width', 185);
            $('#rect').css('height', 160);
            $('#rect').toggle();

            abc.on('click', function (event) {
                $('#rect' + id_.split('#')[1]).css('left', tre.left + arr[0]);
                $('#rect' + id_.split('#')[1]).css('top', tre.top + arr[1]);
                $('#rect' + id_.split('#')[1]).toggle();
            });
        });
});
```

CSS:

```
#map a {
    cursor: hand;
}

$('#mapimage').mapster(
    { 
        fillColor: '090'
    });


img:hover {
  border: 5px solid #090;
}

fb-icon{
    background:none;
}

fb-icon:hover{
    background:#03C;
}

#area:hover{
     background:#03C;
}
```

and the image just for testing that i am using is

[image]

Comment: So now you want to change the  color of  numbered boxes.

Comment: Your code `$('#mapimage').mapster({ fillColor: '090' });` should be inside of the `$(window).load(...);` function. Or is that just a copy & paste issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mottie. But this also i tried but not working. Its filling the color in background for whole image. even i changed the div id also.